# SQL Compare pairs of fields and append matches to another field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

We have a large database, and have imported old, archived data from an old schema.  We have created two queries from the new and old data (A and B) and want to 'flag' the fields that have a different values for review.

We have set up a third query, and have manually matched fields up like so:

```
CREATE VIEW vuAB_COMPARISON AS
SELECT
     A.1
    ,B.1
    ,A.2
    ,B.2
    ,A.3
    ,B.3
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ,CASE 
      WHEN A.PK = B.PK 
        THEN 'RecordMatch' 
      WHEN A.PK <> B.PK 
        THEN 'RecordNoMatch' 
     END AS ComparisonCheck

FROM Table A
INNER JOIN Table B
ON A.PK = B.PK
```

What we'd like to do is append to the ComparisonCheck column all the individual fields that don't match.  For example, if A.1<>B.1 then the ComparisonCheck column would be 'RecordMatch;Field1_NoMatch'

Similarly, if A.1 <> B.1 AND A.2 <> B.2 then the ComparisonCheck column would be 'RecordMatch;Field1_NoMatch;Field2_NoMatch'  etc.

The only way I can think about approaching this is with a complicated nested case statement.  However there are a few dozen fields to match so this would be tedius.

Is there a better solution?  I've also thought about splitting this into two queries, but I'm not sure that get's me any closer to the solution.

Note I've simplified things a bit as in reality the join uses multiple fields, and not all records from queries A/B match, which is why the CASE statement is set up how it is.

Comment: There will be no records to satisfy this: WHEN A.PK <> B.PK, since the 2 tables were inner joined. Records where A.PK <> B.PK will be dropped from the result set.

Comment: Is all you are going for here is comparing table a values with table b values for the same pk?

Comment: How are rows from the two tables matched (i.e.: the JOIN condition)? I know it's tempting to say "row 1 in `A` matches row 1 in `B`" but ordering is meaningless in SQL without an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @Twelfth Yes.  We've successfully joined the records with PKs, now we want to flag individual fields that aren't consistent.

Comment: @ZoffDino We've set up 5 fields that act as a composite PK, which we've performed a join on.

Comment: @wewesthemenace yes you are right - but I've simplified the join clause in the example for clarity.  Sorry if that caused confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UNPIVOT or CROSS APPLY can make this work easier.

Assume you have two tables below:

```
create table t1 (id int, c1 int, c2 int, c3 int);
create table t2 (id int, c1 int, c2 int, c3 int);

insert into t1 values(0,0,0,0);
insert into t1 values(1,1,1,1);
insert into t1 values(2,2,2,2);
insert into t1 values(3,3,3,3);
--insert into t1 values(4,null,3,3);
--insert into t1 values(5,null,3,3);
insert into t1 values(6,3,3,3); --t2's missing record

insert into t2 values(0,0,0,0); --match
insert into t2 values(1,1,2,1); --c2 mismatch
insert into t2 values(2,2,3,3); --c2,c3 mismatch
insert into t2 values(3,2,2,2); --all mismatch
--insert into t2 values(4,null,3,3);
--insert into t2 values(5,3,null,3);
insert into t2 values(7,2,2,2); --t1's missing record
```

### Compare Steps:

- Unpivot t1 and t2, transfer columns to rows by generating c_name column.
- Full outer join from two vertical tables

  - Compare ids can figure out the missing Recoreds
  - Compare values can figure out the unmatched columns

```
with 
vt1 as 
  (select id, c_name , v1
   from t1
   unpivot (v1 for c_name in ([c1],[c2],[c3]) ) as t),
vt2 as 
  (select id, c_name , v2
   from t2
   unpivot (v2 for c_name in ([c1],[c2],[c3]) ) as t)
select distinct coalesce(vt1.id,vt2.id) as id
  ,case when vt1.id is null and vt2.id is not null
        then 'RecordT1Missing' 
        when vt2.id is null and not vt1.id is null
        then 'RecordT2Missing'
        else 'RecordMatch' end as RecordMatchType
  ,case when v1<>v2 then vt1.c_name + '_NoMatch'
        else '' end as ColumnMathType
from vt1
full outer join vt2
on vt1.id=vt2.id and vt1.c_name = vt2.c_name
;
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d8330/4)</kbd>

Here is the output, not the format as described in the question, but there are many ways to pivot back to other readable format, that work could be left for the OP:

```
ID  RECORDMATCHTYPE COLUMNMATHTYPE
 0      RecordMatch 
 1      RecordMatch 
 1      RecordMatch    c2_NoMatch
 2      RecordMatch    
 2      RecordMatch    c2_NoMatch
 2      RecordMatch    c3_NoMatch
 3      RecordMatch    c1_NoMatch
 3      RecordMatch    c2_NoMatch
 3      RecordMatch    c3_NoMatch
 6  RecordT2Missing 
 7  RecordT1Missing
```

### NOTE:

- All data values in my sample defined as integer, but in real scenario may have different data types, should be convert into varchar before unpivot and compare.
- Unfortunately SqlServer unpivot can not keep null values, so I commented all the data witin null values. You could also add conditions to handle with those null values, but I think the better solution is transfer null values to some unused values, unless you have further logic to deal with the null values.

### UPDATE:

With @ErikE's help, use CROSS APPLY can handle null values more easily.

```
with 
vt1 as 
  (select id, c_name , v1
   from t1
   CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('c1',c1),('c2',c2),('c3',c3))
            CrossApplied (c_name, v1) ),
vt2 as 
  (select id, c_name , v2
   from t2
   CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('c1',c1),('c2',c2),('c3',c3))
            CrossApplied (c_name, v2) )
select distinct coalesce(vt1.id,vt2.id) as id
  ,case when vt1.id is null and vt2.id is not null
        then 'RecordT1Missing' 
        when vt2.id is null and not vt1.id is null
        then 'RecordT2Missing'
        else 'RecordMatch' end as RecordMatchType
  ,case when v1<>v2 then vt1.c_name + '_NoMatch'
        when v1 is null and v2 is not null and vt1.id is not null then vt1.c_name + '_T1Missing'
        when v2 is null and v1 is not null and vt2.id is not null then vt1.c_name + '_T2Missing'
        else '' end as ColumnMathType
from vt1
full outer join vt2
on vt1.id=vt2.id and vt1.c_name = vt2.c_name
;
```

With those data have null values, will get the result below:

```
ID  RECORDMATCHTYPE COLUMNMATHTYPE
 0      RecordMatch     
 1      RecordMatch     
 1      RecordMatch       c2_NoMatch
 2      RecordMatch       
 2      RecordMatch       c2_NoMatch
 2      RecordMatch       c3_NoMatch
 3      RecordMatch       c1_NoMatch
 3      RecordMatch       c2_NoMatch
 3      RecordMatch       c3_NoMatch
 4      RecordMatch     
 5      RecordMatch     
 5      RecordMatch     c1_T1Missing
 5      RecordMatch     c2_T2Missing
 6  RecordT2Missing     
 7  RecordT1Missing
```

It can figure out the missing data in which column and which table of ID 5.

Comment: Or use `CROSS_APPLY` to unpivot and preserve NULLs intact!

Comment: @ErikE Thanks for your help! I updated in my answer.

Comment: Exactly so, you got it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a generic table compare set of scripts:

FInd records in a, but not in b

```
Select * from tablea a left join tableb b on b.pk = a.pk where b.pk is null
```

Simple logic, left joins produce nulls when a pk is in tablea but not b, where b.pk is null gives us all in a not b.

reverse the tables to get in b but not a:

```
    Select * from tableb b left join tablea a on b.pk = a.pk where a.pk is null
```

same logic, just reversing which table is first and the null check.  Technically you could use a right join instead of changing which table is first in the from clause

and the differences between the tables:

```
select a.*,b.* from tablea a inner join tableb b on a.pk = b.pk
where a.col1 <> b.col1 or a.col2 <> col2 or a.col3 <> a.col3 or etc...
```

That will simply list all rows that are different between tables.  Unfortuantely you do need to type each column out in the where clause.  To change this to a flag:

```
select a.pk, case when c.pk is not null then "no match' else 'match found' end
from tablea a 
inner join tableb b on a.pk = b.pk
left join ( select a.pk from tablea a inner join tableb b on a.pk = b.pk
where a.col1 <> b.col1 or a.col2 <> col2 or a.col3 <> a.col3 or etc...) c
on a.pk = c.pk
```

Logic is using a subquery to pick out all PK's that have a difference in a subquery and left joining to it from tablea.  If c.pk is null, then it's not in the subquery and the rows are the same, if c.pk is not null then there is a difference in the row...a simple case statement changes that into a flag.

Comment: Tip: `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3 EXCEPT SELECT b.col1, b.col2, b.col3)`

Comment: Thanks for this.  However this will only flag the PK's.  I'm looking to flag each field that doesn't match between records.  This may be 0 fields, 1 field, 15 fields.  Your case logic would work, but would be very tedious to set up and work with.

Comment: @higy er...not sure if you understand the bottom query there.  The mass or statements in the where clause will pick out when fields are different...the case statement is relatively simple.  Take the bottom query there...it will give the pk and a flag for match/no match.  The tedious part will be expanding the where statement to include the compare of 15 columns